# b21 Rflex intermittant start and stops on ATRV jr

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Rlfex-B21 driver for ATRV jr and publishing the velocity

rostopic pub -1 /b21/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0.8,0,0]' '[0,0,0]'

I am expect that the robot should should continuously move, but it doing move-stop-move
at random intervals.

any help?????

rob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12330/b21-rflex-intermittant-start-and-stops-on-atrv-jr/) by [robpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1526/robpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we were recently trying to do the same with our B21-robot and by comparing the code with the Player-Stage code from which it was ported from, we found a fix for some hardware-bug. Applying  that patch to the ROS-code solved it for us. (see: http://answers.ros.org/question/1863/rflexb21-cmd_vel-not-working-as-expected )

You can get the patch here:

[http://ias.cs.tum.edu/~kargm/rflex_driver.patch](http://ias.cs.tum.edu/%7Ekargm/rflex_driver.patch)

and apply it to rflex_driver.cc in your reflex ROS-package. Let me know it this solved it for you.

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general when sending command velocities, you need to publish continually, not just once. Try something like:

```
rostopic pub -r 10 /b21/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0.8,0,0]' '[0,0,0]'
```

This protects against losing control of the robot when bad things happen (like network interruptions, or controller node crashes).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1526/robpan/) on 2011-12-14**:
Thanks for the reply, I try setting the constant frequency ( 10,20, 100 etc), but same issue. I am just wondering that since i am using telecom port (ttyR0) instead of USB(ttyUSB0) serial, would that be the issue?